# Weird JavaScript scrolling / rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Today I'm facing a very strange issue.

I created a div containing about 10 complex elements. These elements contain several more divs with CSS3 transitions, animations and translations.

The outer div is quite wide and inside a scroll container:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="scroller">
        <div class="animated-element">
            [...]
        </div>
        <div class="animated-element">
            [...]
        </div>
        [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm now using jQuery (I tried plain JSS too) to move the scroller inside the container:

```
document.getElementById('scroller').style.left = "-150px";
// or
$('#scroller').animate({"left" : "-150px"}, 500);
```

The strange thing is happening now. After scrolling the element, nothing changes. First I thought it would be a typo or something in the script.

But then I moved the cursor over the scroller and as long as I moved it back and forth, the changes I made (using JS) were showing up.

I searched a lot for rerendering, but couldn't find anything useful.

I built these kind of sliders like thousands of times. This is why this issue confuses me so much.

I'll try to put together a fiddle tomorrow, when I'm back at the office. But I hope that someone might have an idea or even a solution.

**Edit 2**

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/ryrrY/).

I figured out that scrolling works if I remove the `perspective`  `perspective-origin` **and** `position:relative` properties from the single `.moreitem`s. In the full context something seems to interrupt. *The cut-out works anyway*.

**Edit 1** Here is the CSS of the scroller:

```
-webkit-box-align:center;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack:start;
display:-webkit-box;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
```

Comment: Does the `#scroller` itself have some special CSS?

Comment: Yes. I edited my question and added the CSS. I'll post a fiddle tomorrow.

Comment: When exactly is `$('#scroller').animate({"left" : "-150px"}, 500);` ran?

Comment: Would be better if you would some demo is something like jsfiddle.net....

Comment: It's fired by onclick (or for now from the console). If you'd have read my entire question, you'd know that a fiddle is my plan for today :)

Comment: It's getting more and more weird. I created a fiddle, copy and pasted the original code from my page and it works perfect. I don't know what to do anymore…

Comment: I did a **LOT** of trial and error. I found the problem, but not a solution. It seems as some stuff is effecting each other. In the full context it works only if I remove the `perspective` and `perspective-origin`. The cut-out works anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/ryrrY/

Answer (score 0):

Safari is prone to glitches of not rerendering dynamic content. I ran into this yesterday with CSS3 columns.

Not sure if this is the heart of your problem, or just a minor glitch that's distracting from the real problem, but try forcing a rerender after the animation:

```
$('.morecontainer').toggle().toggle();
```

Or, as part of the animation, you could move (or animate in some other way) a transparent div with `position:absolute` and `z-index:-1` that lies underneath `.morecontainer`, which may force a rerender during each step of the animation.